# Split year quarterly using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to accomplish something in javascript but I don't know if it's possible.

This is what I would like to do:

I'm trying to build a media calendar that when the user selects a day from the jQuery Datepicker calendar it would auto populate another text box with the quarter number of the year.

Like Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4.

The problem is that for the media calendar starts the first calendar Monday of the year so for example 12/31/2019 was a Monday so it would be part of Q1 2020 and same with the last day of the year, this year Q4 ends in 12/27/2020 and Q1 2021 starts on 12/28/2020 etc.

What function could I create to give me Q1 as the first monday of the calendar year and Q4 as the last sunday of the calendar year?

Answer (score 0):

The quarters of the year are:

- Q1: 1 January – 31 March
- Q2: 1 April – 30 June
- Q3: 1 July – 30 September
- Q4: 1 Octomber - 31 December.

```js
var dt = new Date();

var day = dt.getDate();
var dayOfWeek = dt.getDay();
var month = dt.getMonth();
var year = dt.getFullYear();

let dayName = "";
switch(dayOfWeek){
    case 0 : dayName = "Sunday"; break;
    case 1 : dayName = "Monday";break;
    case 2 : dayName = "Tuesday";break;
    case 3 : dayName = "Wednesday";break;
    case 4 : dayName = "Thursday";break;
    case 5 : dayName = "Friday";break;
    case 6 : dayName = "Saturday";break;
}

let MonthName = "";
switch(month){
    case 0 : MonthName = "January"; break;
    case 1 : MonthName = "February";break;
    case 2 : MonthName = "March";break;
    case 3 : MonthName = "April";break;
    case 4 : MonthName = "May";break;
    case 5 : MonthName = "June";break;
    case 6 : MonthName = "July";break;
    case 7 : MonthName = "August"; break;
    case 8 : MonthName = "September";break;
    case 9 : MonthName = "Octomber";break;
    case 10 : MonthName = "November";break;
    case 11 : MonthName = "December";break;
}

console.log(dayName+" "+day+"/"+MonthName+"/"+year);

//check if it's 1 day of year or month == Jan,Feb,Mar
if( (month >= 0 || day == 1) && month <= 3){
  console.log("Quarter: Q1");
}else if(month >= 4 && month <= 6){
  console.log("Quarter: Q2");
}else if(month >= 7 && month <= 9){
  console.log("Quarter: Q3");
}else if(month >= 10 && month <= 12){
  console.log("Quarter: Q4");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the quarters for the media calendar are specified how I mentioned above, Q1 starts on the first calendar monday so for 2020 Q1 starts on 12/30/2019 as it's the first monday and Q4 ends on 12/27 as it's the last sunday

Comment: @Codenator20792 For 2021, Q1 starts from 12.30.2020?

Comment: For 2021 Q1, it starts on 12/28/2020 as it's the first Monday where 2021 starts and Q4 ends on 12/26/2021 as it's the last Sunday of the year because 2022 starts on Saturday, all that week would be considered Q1 of 2022

Comment: here's the media calendar for those years https://ibb.co/xgFp1MH

Comment: @Codenator20792 you should find a pattern how it goes each year and write the cases.It won't be easy.

Comment: the pattern is that Q1 starts the first Monday of the week that contains the 1st day of the year and ends the last Sunday of March and so on

Comment: @Codenator20792 the last sunday of March, it's the last day of the month? How we will test that?

Comment: I know :( that's where it gets hard. This year Q1 ends on 03/29 which is the last Sunday of march. I wonder if theres a way to grab the day names and then get all the weeks of each month and somehow do a function that will end Q1 the Sunday of last week of the month of march

Comment: @Codenator20792 You should check each year separately, to find the last sunday of a month you should know the start and end day.That changes each year

Comment: I see your edit! Looks good! I'm just confused with what happens if the first monday to start Q1 is december 30th like this year? 2020 Q1 started last monday

Comment: @Codenator20792 try to modify the code according to your needs.